# I upgraded my expo sdk from 39 to 41 and my expo simulator wont open

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator

After i ran `expo upgrade` and tried to run `expo start` my app cant run :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade your Expo Go app.

If you are using a simulator in IOS or Andriod use the appropriate command below:

```
# For IOS    
$ expo client:install:ios

# For Android
$ expo client:install:android
```